# error: enum was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I added a new value (NULL_IS_NOT_NIL) to an enum in ksql.h

```
enum
{
    PKEY                  = 0x000001,
    NONCOLUMN             = 0x000010,
    EXPRESSION            = 0x000010,
    INSERTONLY            = 0x000100,
    NUMERIC               = 0x001000,
    NULL_IS_NOT_NIL       = 0x010000,

    MAXLEN_TABLENAME      = 50
};
```

Unfortunately, this:

```
Row.SetExtras ("COMMENT2", KROW::NULL_IS_NOT_NIL);
```

Throws an error.

```
db.cpp:7727: error: âNULL_IS_NOT_NILâ was not declared in this scope
```

On the other hand

```
Row.SetExtras ("COMMENT2", 0x010000);
```

and

```
Row.SetExtras (vendor_id,  KROW::NUMERIC);
```

Both work fine and do not throw errors. Right now I can get by by replacing NULL_IS_NOT_NIL with 0x010000, but that is a bad idea. Is there a reason that I am getting this error? Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: Funny question, but are the changes in the header being reflected? I know that in my environment, I can sometimes forget to save a header and it won't compile with the changes. So if you comment out the `NUMERIC` line, will the `KROW::NUMERIC` stop working?

Comment: Yeah, this was really confusing to me.  Is there a good way to tell if changes in the header are being reflected properly?

Comment: I added something you can do to make sure. Go the opposite way: break code that works currently.

Comment: Good catch Chris.  Commenting out numeric does not break the build, so the error is that the header file is not updating properly.  I'd better check my makefile.  Thanks!

Comment: Check if you have an old copy of the header file in another directory on the include path.

Comment: Alright.  Chris was correct, one of the libraries I was editing was not being pushed to the correct folder.  I'm just waiting for him to answer the question now so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the changes in the header file, but they are not being reflected in your project. As stated in the comments, the cause was due to it not being pushed to the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give the `enum` a name: `KROW` is missing from your code snippet.

On the other hand, if you call it `KROW`, you will get a redefinition error. So you need to come up with a different solution. (Unless you are editing the system header file directly -- but surely not...)

Comment: I think the enum is in the `KROW` namespace or scope, since older enum values weem to work. Enum names are not used for the values (this changes in C++11 with class enums)

Comment: @juanchopanza, A class, actually. There was a previous answer like this ;)

Comment: It is a library header file, not a system header file and I am editing it.